# Laravel 5.5 - Forgot password API Route

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 5.5 app that is working great, I have PassPort setup and can use the reset password function.

But I am now looking for a way to trigger the forgotten password email via the API route.

The oAuth route seems to be automatically setup, do I need to manually create a route for the forgotten password function?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the forgotten password email route as described below, but keep in mind that it uses CSRF protection and I strongly recommend not disabling it for that route for security reasons.

If you want to use the route, the route name is `password.reset`, the method `POST` and the controller action is

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset
```

However, another option, a much cleaner one, is to create a new controller, use the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait and create your own routes.

The new controller will look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function sendResetLinkEmail()
    {
        // You can override the method here, if you want.
    }
}
```